# twitter app using java

Tags: java, twitter

I'm trying to make a simple Twitter application in Eclipse. I'm getting a "Resource not found" error. I have tried using a simple Java class, as well as a Servlet.

My code: TwitterIntegration.java:

```
package com.home.social; 
import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
import java.io.FileWriter; 
import java.util.List; 
import twitter4j.Query; 
import twitter4j.QueryResult; 
import twitter4j.Status; 
import twitter4j.Twitter; 
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory; 
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder; 

public class TwitterIntegration { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    { 
        // Create configuration builder and set key, token etc 
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder(); 
        cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("xx"); 
        cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("xx"); 
        cb.setOAuthAccessToken("xx"); 
        cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xx"); 
        // Create Twitter instance 
        Twitter Twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance(); 
        // Create file writer and buffer writer
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("Twitterstream.txt",true); 
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream); 
        // Create Query object and set search string 
        Query query = new Query(""); 
        query.setQuery("#Mumbai"); 
        // Get query result 
        QueryResult qr = Twitter.search(query); 
        // Get tweets and write in the file 
        while(qr.hasNext())
        { 
            qr.nextQuery(); 
            List<Status> tweets = qr.getTweets(); 
            for (Status t: tweets)
            { 
                System.out.println(t.getId() + " - " + t.getCreatedAt() + ": " + t.getText()); 
                out.write("\n"+t.getId()+","); out.write("\t"+t.getText()+","); 
                out.write("\t"+t.getUser()+","); 
                } 
            } 
        try{ Thread.sleep(1000*60*15); 
        }catch(Exception e) {} 
        } 
    }
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>
    Twitter3</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/HTTPRequest
    at twitter4j.AlternativeHttpClientImpl.handleRequest(AlternativeHttpClientImpl.java:43)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:53)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:71)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1562)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.search(TwitterImpl.java:253)
    at com.home.social.TwitterIntegration.main(TwitterIntegration.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Post your full stacktrace please.

Comment: sorry what is stacktrace? I have posted full code here.

Comment: [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Comment: Improved grammar & formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [Google AppEngine API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction) jar file. You have to install/download it and add it to your project.